# Difference between Nominatim and Overpass-Api?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

What is the difference between Nominatim and Overpass-Api?

What can't I do with Nominatim that I can do with the overpass-api ?

Comment: In your research so far what have you found to be any evident differences?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 6):

[Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is a *geocoder* and *reverse-geocoder*. You can search for an address and it will return the location. Likewise you can search for a location and it will return its full address hierarchy. Nominatim usually only returns address-related tags from OSM.

[Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) instead can query for *all* tags in OSM. You can search for POIs, parking spaces, roads, rivers, speed cameras, traffic lights, ... However it just allows you to search for *raw tags*. It doesn't know about addresses (except for the raw address tags in OSM), especially it lacks the knowledge of address hierarchies.

For a better understanding of their differences and specific use-cases take a look at the [Nominatim examples](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example) and [Overpass API exmaples](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Usage_examples:_Simple_queries_for_tags_and_bounding_boxes) in the OSM wiki.

Comment: Overpass API feature list looks somewhat incomplete, which is probably due to the language guide cited (it's a bit dated). For a better idea on what is possible, I'd recommend to take a look at the following wiki page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL -

Comment: Hi, what OSM does mean?

Comment: OSM stands for OpenStreetMap in this context.